# How to do one big select from table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to show the data from DB into a table of report file.

`my_table` looks like:

```
+----+-------+------+------+-------------------+-----------+-------+----+-------------------+
| id |entryID|userID|active|    dateCreated    |affiliateId|premium|free|     endDate       |
|  1 | 69856 |   1  |   N  |2014-03-22 13:54:49|     1     |   N   | N  |2014-03-22 13:54:49|   
|  2 | 63254 |   2  |   Y  |2014-03-21 13:35:15|     2     |   Y   | N  |                   |
|  3 | 56324 |   3  |   N  |2014-03-21 11:11:22|     2     |   Y   | N  |2014-02-22 16:44:46|
|  4 | 41256 |   4  |   Y  |2014-03-21 08:10:46|     1     |   N   | Y  |                   |
| .. |  ...  |  ... |  ... |        ...        |    ...    |  ...  | .. |   ...             | 
+----+-------+------+------+-------------------+-----------+-------+----+-------------------+
```

I need to create the table with data from `my_table`

```
| Date | № of Entries (in that date) | Total № of Entries | Premium | Free | Afiiliate |
```

The final table in file should looks like:

Report 17-07-2013:

```
+----------+--------------+-------+---------+------+-----------+
|   Date   | № of Entries | Total | Premium | Free | Afilliate |
|2013-07-17|      2       | 99845 |    2    |   0  |     0     |
|2013-07-18|      1       | 99843 |    0    |   1  |     0     |
|2013-07-22|      1       | 99842 |    1    |   0  |     1     |
|2013-07-23|      3       | 99841 |    2    |   1  |     2     |
|2013-07-24|     298      | 99838 |   32    |  273 |    25     |
|2013-07-25|    5526      | 99540 |  474    | 5058 |   126     |   
|2013-07-26|    1686      | 94014 |  157    | 1532 |    56     | 
|2013-07-27|    1673      | 92328 |  156    | 1517 |    97     |
|2013-07-28|    1461      | 90655 |  155    | 1310 |    83     |
|   ...    |     ...      |  ...  |   ...   |  ... |    ...    |
+----------+--------------+-------+---------+------+-----------+
```

Should I for each column do a `SELECT` or I should do only 1 select?
If it possible to do 1 select how to do it?

It should be by analogy with this report:
[report](http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/15/0722/h_1437597193_5941024_287b307eaa.png)

Some fields differ (like 'Number of Entries in that  date').

Total number of Entries means: all entries from beginning to the that specific date.
Number of Entries in that date means: all entries in that date. 
In a final table the date from column Date will not repeat, that's why Column 'Number of Entries (in that date)' will calculate all entries for that date.

Comment: Do u mean to create a file with the data where date matches something like '17-07-2013' or you want to create a new table and insert that selected data there?

Comment: This new table can be in a file or in the web page. But it is not a new table in DB.

Comment: assuming by "1 select" you mean `select *` that can only show you the columns in their literal database order, left to right. for any other order you must deliberately specify each column in the sequence you want.

Comment: I couldn't see other fields like free, premium etc where are they residing?

Comment: The table I will create with a writer which I already have. The result table will be displayed on a web page and will be send to the e-mail. I suppose that it will be csv format. I was thinking that I will create an Object with variables like the columns of the table from db, and then write this data to the table. But I'm not sure if it is the best way to  do it.

Comment: It's very unclear how the data in the report relates to the contents of the input table. None of the dates in the report match the dates in the table. What are the the # of Entries columns counting? Where does Free come from?

Comment: @Dylan - what programming language is the website? PHP? ASP.Net ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLFiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20cc0/5

The added column `entryID` does not matter for us.

I don't really understand what you want for `Total`, or the criteria for `affiliateID`. This query should get you started.

```
SELECT 
  DATE(dateCreated) as "Date", 
  count(dateCreated) as "No of Entries",
  99845 as Total,
  sum( case when premium='Y' then 1 else 0 end ) as Premium,
  sum( case when premium='N' then 1 else 0 end ) as Free,
  sum( case when affiliateID IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as Affiliate

 FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY DATE(dateCreated)
 ORDER BY Date ASC
```

> The final table in file should looks like:
>   ... This new table can be in a file or in the web page. But it is not a new table in DB. –

It sounds like you may be new to this area so I just wanted to inform you that spitting out a report into a **file** for a **website** is highly unusual and typically only done when your data is completely separate from the website. Putting data from a database onto a website (like the query we made here) is very common and it's very likely you don't need to mess with any files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir!

Answer (score 3):

Your result is not so clear for the total is a count or sum and affiliate is sum or count also

but assuming total will be count and affiliate will be sum

here a query you might use to give you a result ( using ms-sql )

```
select DateCreated,count(EntryId) as Total,
       sum(case when Premium='Y' then 1 else 0 end) as Premium,
       sum(case when Premium='N' then 1 else 0 end) as Free,
       sum(AffiliateId) as Affiliate
from sample
group by DateCreated
```

here a working [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c8bc/1)

if I didn't understood you correctly, kindly advise

hope it will help you

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when displaying the table. There is one more column id.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir!

Answer (score 2):

```
   select date(DateCreated),count(entryId) as Total,
       sum(case when Premium='Y' then 1 else 0 end) as Premium,
       sum(case when Premium='N' then 1 else 0 end) as Free,
       sum( case when affiliateID IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as Affiliate
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/myfile.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
from my_table
group by date(DateCreated) order by date(DateCreated);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir!